# ocutar um botao FeatureDiscovery quando for para mobile e exibir quanod for para desktop

Tags: php, javascript, css, html5

estou usando o materialize, e um recurso chamado FeatureDiscovery, editei o materialize para fazer aparecer minha nav bar quando for clicado porém, gostaria que ele sumisse quando entrar em uma tela mobile, e aparecesse somente o menu da navbar para mobile, segue o codigo do meu menu

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.tap-target');
  var instances = M.TapTarget.init(elems);
});


$('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sidenav').sidenav();
});
```

```css
/*!
 * Materialize v1.0.0 (http://materializecss.com)
 * Copyright 2014-2017 Materialize
 * MIT License (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dogfalo/materialize/master/LICENSE)
 */

html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 0) {
  html {
font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  html {
font-size: 14.5px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  html {
font-size: 15px;
  }
}
.tap-target-wrapper {
  width: 197%;
  height: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s .0s;
  transition: visibility 0s .0s;
}

.tap-target-wrapper.open {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s;
  transition: visibility 0s;
}

.tap-target-wrapper.open .tap-target {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1);
  opacity: .95;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1), opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1), opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}

.tap-target-wrapper.open .tap-target-wave::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      transform: scale(1);
}

.tap-target-wrapper.open .tap-target-wave::after {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: pulse-animation 1s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0, 0.38, 1) infinite;
      animation: pulse-animation 1s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0, 0.38, 1) infinite;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s,
 visibility 0s 1s,
 -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s,
 visibility 0s 1s,
 -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s,
 transform .3s,
 visibility 0s 1s;
  transition: opacity .3s,
 transform .3s,
 visibility 0s 1s,
 -webkit-transform .3s;
}

/*deixa eedondo*/
/*.tap-target {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ee6e73;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 10px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 30px 10px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      box-shadow: 0 20px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 10px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 30px 10px -20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1), opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1), opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1), -webkit-transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
}*/

.tap-target-content {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
}

.tap-target-wave {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10001;
}

.tap-target-wave::before, .tap-target-wave::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.tap-target-wave::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
      transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: transform .3s;
  transition: transform .3s, -webkit-transform .3s;
}

.tap-target-wave::after {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s,
 visibility 0s,
 -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s,
 visibility 0s,
 -webkit-transform .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s,
 transform .3s,
 visibility 0s;
  transition: opacity .3s,
 transform .3s,
 visibility 0s,
 -webkit-transform .3s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tap-target-origin {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10002;
  position: absolute !important;
}

.tap-target-origin:not(.btn):not(.btn-large):not(.btn-small), .tap-target-origin:not(.btn):not(.btn-large):not(.btn-small):hover {
  background: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .tap-target, .tap-target-wrapper {
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
  }
}

/* 2dp elevation modified*/
.z-depth-1, nav, .card-panel, .card, .toast, .btn, .btn-large, .btn-small, .btn-floating, .dropdown-content, .collapsible, .sidenav {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.sidenav span.badge {
  margin-top: calc(24px - 11px);
}

nav {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #ee6e73;
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
}

nav.nav-extended {
  height: auto;
}

nav.nav-extended .nav-wrapper {
  min-height: 56px;
  height: auto;
}

nav.nav-extended .nav-content {
  position: relative;
  line-height: normal;
}

nav a {
  color: #fff;
}

nav i,
nav [class^="mdi-"], nav [class*="mdi-"],
nav i.material-icons {
  display: block;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
}

nav .nav-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  nav a.sidenav-trigger {
display: none;
  }
}

nav .sidenav-trigger {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 56px;
  margin: 0 18px;
}

nav .sidenav-trigger i {
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
}

nav .brand-logo {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 2.1rem;
  padding: 0;
}

nav .brand-logo.center {
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
      transform: translateX(-50%);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  nav .brand-logo {
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  nav .brand-logo.left, nav .brand-logo.right {
padding: 0;
-webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
  }
  nav .brand-logo.left {
left: 0.5rem;
  }
  nav .brand-logo.right {
right: 0.5rem;
left: auto;
  }
}

nav .brand-logo.right {
  right: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
}

nav .brand-logo i,
nav .brand-logo [class^="mdi-"], nav .brand-logo [class*="mdi-"],
nav .brand-logo i.material-icons {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

nav .nav-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 32px;
  padding: 28px 0;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

nav ul a {
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s;
  transition: background-color .3s;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul a.btn, nav ul a.btn-large, nav ul a.btn-small, nav ul a.btn-large, nav ul a.btn-flat, nav ul a.btn-floating {
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

nav ul a.btn > .material-icons, nav ul a.btn-large > .material-icons, nav ul a.btn-small > .material-icons, nav ul a.btn-large > .material-icons, nav ul a.btn-flat > .material-icons, nav ul a.btn-floating > .material-icons {
  height: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

nav ul a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

nav ul.left {
  float: left;
}

nav form {
  height: 100%;
}

nav .input-field {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

nav .input-field input {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: none;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}

nav .input-field input:focus, nav .input-field input[type=text]:valid, nav .input-field input[type=password]:valid, nav .input-field input[type=email]:valid, nav .input-field input[type=url]:valid, nav .input-field input[type=date]:valid {
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
}

nav .input-field label {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

nav .input-field label i {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  -webkit-transition: color .3s;
  transition: color .3s;
}

nav .input-field label.active i {
  color: #fff;
}

.navbar-fixed {
  position: relative;
  height: 56px;
  z-index: 997;
}

.navbar-fixed nav {
  position: fixed;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  nav.nav-extended .nav-wrapper {
min-height: 64px;
  }
  nav, nav .nav-wrapper i, nav a.sidenav-trigger, nav a.sidenav-trigger i {
height: 64px;
line-height: 64px;
  }
  .navbar-fixed {
height: 64px;
  }
}

.sidenav .collapsible,
.sidenav.fixed .collapsible {
  border: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
      box-shadow: none;
}

.sidenav .collapsible li,
.sidenav.fixed .collapsible li {
  padding: 0;
}

.sidenav .collapsible-header,
.sidenav.fixed .collapsible-header {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  line-height: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 0 16px;
}

.sidenav .collapsible-header:hover,
.sidenav.fixed .collapsible-header:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

.sidenav .collapsible-header i,
.sidenav.fixed .collapsible-header i {
  line-height: inherit;
}

.sidenav .collapsible-body,
.sidenav.fixed .collapsible-body {
  border: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.sidenav .collapsible-body li a,
.sidenav.fixed .collapsible-body li a {
  padding: 0 23.5px 0 31px;
}

ul:not(.browser-default) {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul:not(.browser-default) > li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sidenav span.badge {
  margin-top: calc(24px - 11px);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .hide-on-small-only, .hide-on-small-and-down {
display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .hide-on-med-and-down {
display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .hide-on-med-and-up {
display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .hide-on-med-only {
display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
  .hide-on-large-only {
display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
  .hide-on-extra-large-only {
display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
  .show-on-extra-large {
display: block !important;
  }
}

nav.nav-extended .nav-wrapper {
  min-height: 56px;
  height: auto;
}

nav .nav-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

menu {
  display: block;
}

ul.staggered-list li {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Element Showed -->
<a id="menu" class="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-floating" onclick="$('.tap-target').tapTarget('open')"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
<a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>

<!-- Tap Target Structure -->
<div class="tap-target" data-target="menu">

  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  </ul>

  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>

      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#!">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Mobile</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">Dropdown<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>

<ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
  <li><a href="#!">Sass</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Components</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Javascript</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">Mobile</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

está meio zuado porque tentei colocar uma parte do codigo css do materialize.
para desktop funciona, meu menu aparece normal, ai quando vai para tela menor, quando uso inspecionar, se eu clicar nao faz nada, bom na verde ele exibe algo branco, mas nao da para ver, eu acho, mas eu gostaria que ele sumisse e ficasse somente o menu do navbar

Comment: Pq vc não usa os seus `@media` para dar ``display:none/block` nesse menu?

Comment: na max 600?          neste caso aqui @media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  .hide-on-med-and-up {
display: none !important;
  }
}                mas eu devo especificar qual button devo bloquear no caso ele chama minha div por meio  do onclick="$('.tap-target').tapTarget('open')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo... Não olhei muito o seu código mas entendi o seu problema. Irei lhe mostrar um exemplo de o que deve-se fazer para remover algo para desktop ou mobile:

HTML:

```
<div class="div-mobile">
    <p>Esta div irá sumir no desktop e aparecerá no mobile.</p>
</div>

<div class="div-desktop">
    <p>Esta div irá sumir no moboile e aparecerá no desktop.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 500px){
    /* Esta div irá sumir quando estiver em telas menores a 500px (celulares) */
    .div-mobile{
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 501px){
    /* Esta div irá sumir quando estiver em telas maiores a 501px (desktops) */
    .div-desktop{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, não pensei dessa forma, é mais simples que pensei, funciona muito bem

Comment: devo editar e colocar como resolvido?

Comment: onde posso encontrar tamanho certos para todos tiplos de dispositivos? pois isso é em relação a resolução certo?

Comment: existem vários sites que você pode procurar diversos tipos de resoluções.

Comment: um exemplo: http://www.robsonmoulin.com.br/artigos/mobile/resolucao-de-tela-de-smartphones-e-tablets/

Comment: @Joannes se seu problema foi resolvido marque a resposta como resolvido.

Comment: onde vejo a opção de marcar como resolvido?

Comment: embaixo das setas de votar para cima e para baixo